# jQuery progress bar disappears after using .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I've added progress bars to my site and they work perfectly when the page loads. However, I want to reload the div using jQuery .load() and after the div has reloaded the progress bars disappear but everything seems to work perfectly.

Below is an abridged but similar code to what I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateDiv() {
    $("#foo-bar").load("http://sub.domain.tld/page.php");
  }
  setInterval("updateDiv()", 30000);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").progressBar(<?php echo $foo; ?>);
    $("#bar").progressBar(<?php echo $bar; ?>);
  });
</script>
<div id="foo-bar">
  <span id="foo"></span>
  <span id="bar"></span>
</div>
```

I got the progress bar source code from here: http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php

All of the JavaScript/jQuery code is included properly and I've checked the console on Google Chrome and there are no errors or warnings.

Like I said, everything works perfectly until the page is reloaded using .load() and I cannot find the problem. I thought that the error would be something to do a cross-domain JavaScript issue but everything else in the div loads perfectly fine; it's just the progress bars that I'm having a problem with.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are reloading the contents of `foo-bar` which has the progressbar elements, you will have to re-initialize the progressbar after every load of the `foo-bar` element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function progressBar() {
        $("#foo").progressBar( <? php echo $foo; ?> );
        $("#bar").progressBar( <? php echo $bar; ?> );
    }

    function updateDiv() {
        $("#foo-bar").load("http://sub.domain.tld/page.php", progressBar);
    }
    setInterval(updateDiv, 30000);
    progressBar()
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly to reload the progress bars, however, the value of the progress bar isn't changing. The actualy value from the database is updated because it works if I echo the variable on it's own but not in the the JS. I also tried putting the PHP variable into an alert and that didn't work either so is there something that I need to do to update the PHP value to the JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id='value'><?php echo 1123; ?></div>;
    <div id="progress"></div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval(function () {
  let vl = Number($("#value").text());
  $("#value").load(location.href+" #value>*","");  html tag is refresh
  $('#progress').progressbar({ value: vl }); this is very important
}, 5000);

$(function() { 
  $('#progress').progressbar({
    value: 13,
    max: 100
  });
});
</script>
```

$.load is not work at jquery progressbar